Structural pattern matching for checking if a list contains an element
Boto3 lists buckets unhelpfully like this:
{'Buckets': [{'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
              'Name': 'foo'},
             {'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
              'Name': 'bar'},
             {'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 30, 15, 4, 59, 150000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
              'Name': 'baz'}],
 'Owner': {...}}

If I want to know whether a bucket foo is at the start of that list, I can write this:
match s3_response:
    case {"Buckets": [{"Name": "foo", "CreationDate": _}, *_]}:
        print("Bucket 'foo' found")
    case _:
        print("Bucket 'foo' not found")

And I can think of a similar solution if the bucket is known to be at the end.
But what about finding bucket bar which is in the middle of the list of buckets? You might hope you could do this:
match s3_response:
    case {"Buckets": [*_, {"Name": "bar", "CreationDate": _}, *_]}:
        print("Bucket 'bar' found")
    case _:
        print("Bucket 'bar' not found")

But that gives:

SyntaxError: multiple starred names in sequence pattern

Of course I could do things the boring old way, but where's the fun in that:
'bar' in [bucket.get("Name", "") for bucket in s3_response.get("Buckets", [])]


In this particular case, I could use s3.head_bucket(Bucket="bar") but that's not really the point of this question!

I think this could be done only with recursion (if you want to use match)

Ok, so it sounds like this is not a use case match supports. Thanks for confirming. It's odd that you can find things at the start of lists, and at the end, but not in the middle!

anyway - it sounds a reasonable thing for match to support - even with the "two *_" syntax  - You may try to kick the discussion in the Python official Discourse on the "ideas"  topic.

https://discuss.python.org/t/allowing-structural-pattern-matching-to-find-things-in-the-middle-of-lists/60662

The match expression in match..case statements in Python has an special syntax, that is not Python  - so all, possible matches are restricted to what is listed inPEP-0622 .
And what is mentioned there for sequences is:

A sequence pattern looks like [a, *rest, b] and is similar to a list
unpacking. An important difference is that the elements nested within
it can be any kind of patterns, not just names or sequences. It
matches only sequences of appropriate length, as long as all the
sub-patterns also match. It makes all the bindings of its
sub-patterns.

So, there is no match expression equivalent for the in operator - sorry to spoil your fun. The best you can get is using a guard expression in your case - as guard expressions are again valid Python:
match s3_response:
    case {"Buckets": [*buckets] if any((bucket["Name"] == "bar" and "CreationDate" in bucket and len(bucket) == 2) for bucket in buckets):
        print("Bucket 'bar' found")


I suppose you could always add a nested for loop containing a match/case under the first case that looks for the structure you're looking for.

yes. I thought about that - in this particular case, I guess the thing to do is to extract the buckets value, and do a for outside the match...case .
